# Kendo UI Template with textfield and list of values

Tags: forms, list, templates, kendo-ui, parameter-passing

I have a form with a text field and a list of radiobuttons. It is displayed using a window popup. I can pass simple parameters to the template, but I don't know how could I pass a list of values. I need to generate dynamically the list of radiobuttons. I tested using the List View, but it repeats the textfields and labels on my form by each item in the list. Any suggestion?

```
<div id="products">                
   <div id="details" />             
</div>

<script id="tmplSell" type="text/x-kendo-template">

   <div  align="left">
       <p>Please, fill the fields </p> 
       <b>Product:</b> <br /> 
       <input type="text" name="txtProduct" id="txtProduct" class ="k-textbox" /> <br />
       <b>Specify Color:</b>

       <!-- dynamic radio button list -->

       <button type="button" id="Button1" class="k-button" onclick="send(); return false; ">Send</button>&nbsp;
    </div>
</script>   
<script>
   var template = kendo.template($("#tmplSell").html());
   var window = $("#products").data("kendoWindow");

 record = {id:0}; //passing a simple value, I need to pass a list of objects like ({color:"red",available:"5"} {color:"blue", available:"1"}

 var entryHtml = template(record);
 $("#details").html(entryHtml);

  window.open().center();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is from kendo templates documentation ([Overview of templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)), Remember that inside the template you can use javascript expressions

```
<div id="example"></div>

    <script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <ul>
        # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
            <li>#= data[i] #</li>
        # } #
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
        var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());

        //Create some dummy data
        var data = ["Todd", "Steve", "Burke"];

        var result = template(data); //Execute the template
        $("#example").html(result); //Append the result
    </script>
```

In your case, you can access any property using `data[i].color` or `data[i].available`